# numpy.irr Using Monthy Data

Tags: numpy, irr

I am using a series of monthly data for my IRR calculation.
It looks to me that this is set up to return the IRR based on annual data. 
Am I wrong?  How does numpy.irr adjust for time periods?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The time of the period does not matter the numpy.irr processing. As long as it is a period of time, no matter how long it is, like monthly or annually or even every 128 days, numpy.irr can give you the results for the total earns.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. It returns it based on annual data. You have to then readjust it to arrive at an IRR for the periodicity in your case.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47570238/1526703